# CudNN error running TensorFlow: Could not set cudnn filter descriptor: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM

Tags: python, cuda, pycharm, tensorflow, cudnn

I am using Python with the IDE Pycharm on an Ubuntu system with CUDA 7.5 installed and working.

I have just merged the CUDNN files with my general CUDA install.

Now, when I run the deep convolutional nn tutorial from TensorFlow's website, I get the following error:

> F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:383] could not set cudnn filter descriptor: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM

Does anyone know what the source of this problem is?  Is this an issue with my CUDNN install?  (which was sheisty--I just ran `rsync -av ./include/ /usr/local/cuda/include` and `rsync -av ./lib64/ /usr/local/cuda/lib64`, then I re-ran `ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`)...or a typo in the code?

---

Or could it be from somewhere else? (or, even better, does anyone know the fix?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I ran into zero answers on the internet, so I'm going to leave this up in case someone else runs into the same problem.

---

The issue was that cudnn v5 did not work with tensor flow (maybe generally, maybe just on my set up...which, admittedly, is Ubuntu 15.10 instead of the 15.04 supported by CUDA), so I had to step back to cudnn v4.

Assuming that you installed the CUDA 7.5 in the default directory and set up the symbolic link in /usr/local/cuda, simply using CUDNN v4 (from Feb) will get it working.  I just extracted the CUDNN tar file and ran the following commands, with root permissions (from my downloads folder):

```
tar -xvzf cudnn-etc.tgz
cd cuda 

rsync -av ./lib64/ /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/
rsync -av ./include/ /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/

ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue on 16.04 LTS. Please note that if you compile TF from source, you can now use cudnn v5. However the pip version of TF is still (as of July '16) stuck at cudnn v4. It seems that people with Pascal GPUs should install from source since Pascal supports only cudnn v5 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the version 5 of cudnn

See [Github issue #1787](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1787)

The patch [#1794](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/1794) is merged in master so the latest RC of tensorflow (r0.8) [has support for it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/RELEASE.md).

Comment: Ok, great, thanks.  I will update once I finish the project (got everything working now, not going to touch it :)